Unordered list in Markdown overflows in Jupyter Notebook
I have an unordered list in my markdown and a little bit of text overflows.code
After I execute it looks like this,
output
How do I solve this?
I thought this might be a browser issue but then I uploaded it to GitHub and it shows the same thing if seen from other devices.

I don't think it is the cause because HTML should work, too; however, you can make a bulleted list in markdown syntax a lot easier. You can just put the text following a dash or asterisk; there's no need for HTML , see here. As for the extra duplicated text, there was glitch in a recent version where it would randomly grab text from earlier in the text and show it again. Usually it would also change it around slightly. It was fixed. From this one example, I cannot be sure it is the same issue. I'll try to dig up some of those ...

 reports and add the details. You should though specify what version of Jupyter Notebook or JupyterLab is involved.

It looks like this issue here. Were you pasting text from Windows & not fixing the line endings? You can probably either fix the line endings or update your version since it was fixed later. (This report also references line endings being involved.) Earlier GitHub ISSUE report with links.

This is a known issue with line endings from text pasted from Windows machines causing problems and it has been fixed. You may wish to fix the line endings or update your Jupyter software. (The former may be less disruptive to your system if things are working well otherwise.)
Resources for additional details:

Post over a week after OP entitled 'Garbage Value Issue in Jupyter Notebook Markdown Cells'
Official GitHub Issue report about this entitled 'JN7 markdown cells mess'

